# Does std::move invoke the copy operator if it's used as an argument on a && parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>


class carl{
    public:
    int x;

    carl(int y):x(y){

    }


    carl(carl&& other)
    {
    std::cout<<" cons called?"<<std::endl;
    this->x = other.x;
    other.x = 0;
    }


    void operator=(carl&& other){
    std::cout<<"operator called?"<<std::endl;
    this->x = other.x;
    other.x = 0;
    }
};



void funct(carl&& get){
std::cout<<get.x<<std::endl;    
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    carl c(2);
    funct(std::move(c));
    std::cout<<c.x<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

If I remember, there is a special rule for special member functions stating that, *if a class declared a move constructor/operator then that class will not automatically generate copy operators/constructors*.

Based from my example, it seems that move operators and constructors were not invoked but rather it **copied** the value. It was supposed to empty out the value of c' `x` and do the `cout` to confirm but none of that happened. Can anybody clarify what's happening with my code?

Comment: `std::move` by itself doesn't invoke a move operator; all you're doing is passing an r-value reference to `funct` but `funct` isn't actually doing a move.

Comment: you pass argument by (r-value) reference, so no copy or move constructor.

Comment: So passing an r-value reference through `std::move` won't invoke move/copy?

Comment: You can confirm that the copy-constructor is not being used by adding `carl(carl const &) = delete;`

Comment: Here's a rule of thumb: **`std::move()` does NOT move.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no moves happening in your code. `func` takes a reference as a parameter, so passing `std::move(c)` simply binds a reference - no copy or move occurs. The key fact is that `std::move` doesn't move, it just returns an rvalue designating the object. If you took your parameter by value:

```
void func(carl get);
```

Then you would be creating a new object which is initialized using the move constructor (assuming you pass an rvalue to `func`).

Comment: Ahhh i see, so just to clarify. using `std::move` on a `&&` will not invoke copy/move but it will only simply bind the values?

Comment: @CarloBrew Think of references as aliases for the objects they are initialized with. There are references for lvalues (`T&`) and references for rvalues (`T&&`). Initializing a reference with `std::move` or anything else does not cause a copy or move, because no new object is being created. So yes, it will just bind the object to the reference.

Comment: I see thank you. is it the same case if it's `std::forward` ?

Comment: @CarloBrew Yes, `std::forward` just returns an lvalue if the argument is an lvalue, and an rvalue if the argument is an rvalue. It doesn't create a new object and doesn't call any constructors. It's literally a type cast, just like `std::move`.

Answer (score 2):

For your example, this here,

```
void funct(carl&& get) { std::cout<<get.x<<std::endl; }
```

gives exactly the same behaviour as

```
void funct(carl& get) { std::cout<<get.x<<std::endl; }
```

Namely: you pass a reference to a function.

---

Things only change when you *move* the rvalue reference into a new object:

```
void funct(carl&& get)
{   
    auto my_carl = std::move(get); 
    std::cout<<my_carl.x<<std::endl;
}
```

Then the compiler calls the move constructor of `carl` to move the content out of the object instead of doing a copy.